# .htaccess mod rewrite - fake folder to path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I'm trying to make some redirects with .htaccess, and I've managed some redirects but not exactly what I want.

I want something similar to what facebook has, when someone enters to

> http://www.example.com/folder

I want to redirect them to

> http://www.example.com/mypath/myfile.php?user=folder

where folder can be any variable with letters and numbers ([A-Za-z0-9-]+)

I've managed to make it work with rules with extension, eg example.com/folder.htm, but I don't want any extension at all

I've found several examples but none of them work for me. I'm sure that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$  /myfile.php?user=$1 [L,NC]
```

im pretty sure that is what you want.

just make sure you have valid regex, u can check that with some online tools, just search for it

btw the backslash before the minus is import, because its a special character within the character set. maybe you forgot that

Comment: is exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot and worked like a charm.
I just tested about 35 rules but i'm unable to understand exactly how the regular expression works. Thanks again